# Check whether a value exists in a list or not

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to check whether a value exists in my list (`suspect`) or not.
So i've tried this:

```py
suspect = ['A','B','C']
Name = input('Please enter your name')
for Name in suspect:
    if Name == suspect:
        print('Suspect is detected  for 1st level')
    else:
        print('Suspect is not detected  for 1st level')
```

Why this condition is always `false`?
Note: Even when i enter "A" as `Name` value, program returns `Suspect is not detected  for 1st level`

Comment: The second if looks unnecessary

Comment: you overwrite `Name` in your `for` loop. better: `if Name in suspect: ... else: ...`; no `for` loop.

Comment: That's not quite right: Name is not overwritten, but shadowed inside the loop.

Comment: @OlegO, It's overwritten. https://ideone.com/N2V4Ft (`for` loop does not introduce a new namespace.)

Comment: I'm sorry, yes, you're right.

Comment: try this.
for names in suspect:
      if name = names:
         print("detected")
else:
      print("not detected")

Answer (score 2):

- for statement variable `Name` overwrite `Name` assigned earlier.

  - Use other name not to overwrite.

```
Name = input('Please enter your name')  # <--- Name first assigned here.
for Name in suspect:   # But this `Name` overwrite!
```

- The code is comparing a name (`str`) with `suspect` (`list`) which will always return `False`

```
  if Name == suspect:
```

- To check if a value is in a sequence, you can use an `in` operator.

```
>>> 'needle' in ['apple', 'needle', 'banana']
True
>>> 'pineapple' in ['apple', 'needle', 'banana']
False
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I try with this code from 2 day
 :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Name = 'A'
suspect = ['A', 'B', 'C']
print(type(suspect))
for word in suspect:
    if(Name == word):
        print('Suspect is detected  for 1st level')
        break
    else:
        print('Suspect is not detected  for 1st level')
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to know if the value of the variable(Here is Name) is in the suspect list.
So you can use `in` statement like below:

```
if Name in suspect:
    statement
else:
    statement
```